# Sqoop Hdfs Hbase

Tags: hbase, hdfs, sqoop

I have sqooped the data from postgres to HDFS which generated a part-m-00000.deflate . Now i want to create a hbase table and load this data into the Hbase table. can someone help me on this please.

Comment: Do you want to load all the tables?

Comment: @vijayraj34 no not all tables it's a join on two tables that i've loaded in hdfs and now i want to move this file into hbase

Comment: This link might help you - http://www.geoinsyssoft.com/sqoop-import-hbase/